# Get json response without specifying '.json in URL'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, routes

Im working on Rails + AngularJS app. In order to access json response of my app I have to `/something.json` in my angular $resource url instead of just `/something`

is there a way how to fix it?

**Routes**

```
upvote_post_comment PUT  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/upvote(.:format) comments#upvote
      post_comments POST /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)            comments#create
       post_comment GET  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#show
        upvote_post PUT  /posts/:id/upvote(.:format)                   posts#upvote
              posts GET  /posts(.:format)                              posts#index
                    POST /posts(.:format)                              posts#create
               post GET  /posts/:id(.:format)                          posts#show
                    GET  /                                             home#index
```

**PostsController**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all

        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: @posts }
        end
    end
end
```

**Angular serviceProvider**

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('posts', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/posts.json/:id', {id: "@id"})
}]);
```

Comment: I think you can simply add + '.json' to the first param

Comment: I don't believe he wants the `.json` extension in his Angular app?

Comment: It isnt working , with .json in the url means the resource that you are accessing is not returning the content-type as json , but an html. So  try to set the content type from your server as  "application/json" and then see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you are saying by `respond_do` to give a json response only when the format `(.:format) in the routes` is specified as json.

You can modify your controller **PostsController** to respond with json no-matter-what the format is.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
        render json: @posts
    end
end
```

**Note**: After this the format after the url wouldn't matter (be it .json, .xml, nothing). The controller's action wold always return json.

Answer (score 2):

Set default format in routes.rb

```
resources :posts, defaults: { format: :json }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.json` to the end of the URL

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('posts', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/posts/' + id + '.json')
}]);
```